# Is there a way to exclude parts of data that are in the same cell?

Tags: vba

I'm currently trying to write a code that will take a column of cells and clean it up by excluding certain names that are in the column, the difficulty is that the names that I want to exclude are in different spots each time.

I've been trying to find a way to do this with the replace function but I can't find a good way to get rid of multiple names at the same time, and I was looking into the mid function a bit but because of the changing position I couldn't find a way to use that.

For example, if there were three cells
1. "matt, daniel, ryan"
2. "ryan, matt"
3. "daniel"

and I want to cut out both "matt" and "ryan" from the data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include a [mcve] to show what you've done, and what specific problem you're having (i.e., how is the actual output differing from your expected output, or what/where do errors raise, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

See comments for more details, hope this helps:

```vb
Sub clearNames()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'declare and allocate your sheet to a variable

Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row at column 1 ("A")

Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow) 'declare and populate an array with the data

Dim arrExcl() As String: arrExcl = Split("matt,ryan", ",") 'declare and populate an array with strings to exclude


Dim R As Long, X As Long
For R = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData) 'for each row in data array
    For X = LBound(arrExcl) To UBound(arrExcl) 'for each row in the exclusion array
        If InStr(arrData(R, 1), arrExcl(X)) > 0 Then 'if the string is found
            arrData(R, 1) = Replace(arrData(R, 1), arrExcl(X), "") 'replace it with nothing
        End If
    Next X
Next R

ws.Range("B1:B" & lRow) = arrData 'put the data back on the sheet

End Sub
```

It might not be exactly what you want, but should give you a starting point.

[image]